# Customizing the boot screen (Windows Vista)

Tags: windows-vista

Basically I'm trying to customize my boot screen. I was able to do it in Windows XP but the machine I currently use runs Vista. I'm not talking about the one with the progress bar, I'm talking about the one before it which includes the function options (Press F2 to run setup, etc.)

I'd like to change the entire thing, maybe add a wallpaper or use some kind of template (not sure if those are available) It looks ugly and I'm just tired of looking at it.

Comment: "I'm just tired of looking at it." Why? Do you spend all day with your PC on the boot screen?

Comment: Just an idea to keep things fresh and new, I've had this computer for a while and I use it for work so I'm looking for a way to customize this screen at boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not talking about the one with the progress bar, I'm talking about
>   the one before it which includes the function options (Press F2 to run
>   setup, etc.)

What you talk about is the BIOS output screen, which can't be updated or customized. This is defined by the motherboard manufacture in the BIOS.